# Problem when upgrading and then reinstalling brew mongodb-community

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

Today I tried to upgrade my formulaes and one of them was mongodb-community.

I got this error:

```bash
Error: mongodb-community: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
  Actual: 2bb46417f4e8ce8d4bc0537bd50d8bdf5c60cd69751e81f9baf2ddfb8ce1b787
    File: /Users/yuri/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/320fffd33638cf76b75125c59e1b4d39af9b24730cd4572214c4b89675fc896f--mongodb-database-tools-macos-arm64-100.7.3.zip
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I removed the file.

I uninstalled mongodb-community with their mongodb dependencies (sh and database tools).

I tried doing `brew untap <mongo> & brew tap <mongo>`.

Now I am trying to install mongodb-database-tools since it is the formulae that produces the sha256 mismatch.

I do not know what is going on and what could be the source of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue today. I manually changed the "expected" string to the "actual" string by:

1. `brew edit mongodb-database-tools`
2. then I searched that script for for the "e3b0.." string and replaced it with the "2bb4.." string
3. and then I re-ran `brew install mongodb-community`

this worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @peewee said, there is a upstream PR to fix this checksum mismatch issue, https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/pull/189 (and you should always file some similar patch PR whenever you see the checksum mismatch)